# What is the name of different layers in my PyTorch model?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I have the following model in PyTorch:

```
UNet3D(
  (encoders): ModuleList(
    (0): Encoder(
      (basic_module): DoubleConv(
        (SingleConv1): SingleConv(
          (groupnorm): GroupNorm(1, 5, eps=1e-05, affine=True)
          (conv): Conv3d(5, 32, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), stride=(1, 1, 1), padding=(1, 1, 1), bias=False)
          (ReLU): ReLU(inplace=True)
        )
        (SingleConv2): SingleConv(
          (groupnorm): GroupNorm(8, 32, eps=1e-05, affine=True)
          (conv): Conv3d(32, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), stride=(1, 1, 1), padding=(1, 1, 1), bias=False)
          (ReLU): ReLU(inplace=True)
        )
      )
    )
    (1): Encoder(
      (pooling): MaxPool3d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
      (basic_module): DoubleConv(
        (SingleConv1): SingleConv(
          (groupnorm): GroupNorm(8, 64, eps=1e-05, affine=True)
          (conv): Conv3d(64, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), stride=(1, 1, 1), padding=(1, 1, 1), bias=False)
          (ReLU): ReLU(inplace=True)
        )
        (SingleConv2): SingleConv(
          (groupnorm): GroupNorm(8, 64, eps=1e-05, affine=True)
          (conv): Conv3d(64, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), stride=(1, 1, 1), padding=(1, 1, 1), bias=False)
          (ReLU): ReLU(inplace=True)
        )
      )
    )
    (2): Encoder(
      (pooling): MaxPool3d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
      (basic_module): DoubleConv(
        (SingleConv1): SingleConv(
          (groupnorm): GroupNorm(8, 128, eps=1e-05, affine=True)
          (conv): Conv3d(128, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), stride=(1, 1, 1), padding=(1, 1, 1), bias=False)
          (ReLU): ReLU(inplace=True)
        )
        (SingleConv2): SingleConv(
          (groupnorm): GroupNorm(8, 128, eps=1e-05, affine=True)
          (conv): Conv3d(128, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), stride=(1, 1, 1), padding=(1, 1, 1), bias=False)
          (ReLU): ReLU(inplace=True)
        )
      )
    )
```

Could someone please tell me what is the name of different layers here? For example, "encoders (0)"?. I want to extract intermediate layer output from model, so I need the name of each layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The names are given by whats inside the **parentheses**. Be aware that ModuleList is a list type, so the modules within are addressed by index.

The pytorch forums are usually quite good for that. This [post](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-replace-a-layer-or-module-in-a-pretrained-network/60068) describes how you can access and alter a layer, but it similarly applies to register a forward hook. For instance, in your case

```
model.encoders[0].basic_module
```

will get you the basic_module in the first encoder.